# Can someone explain why the Python3.x `in` operator is not working here?

Tags: python-3.x

I am iteratively testing whether or not certain values in a small single-column Dataframe (called `shotList`) exist in a larger, multi-column Dataframe (called `df`) and performing some actions based on this conditional.

The values in both DataFrames are integers of the same type (NumPy.int64); however, not all (but most!) of the values that I am certain are members of both variables are recognized using the `in` operator.

I've verified that the values are of the same type and that they exist in both DataFrames. I also show that the columns containing the values not recognized by the `in` operator are successfully found using `.loc`. I've attached a picture showing this is the case.

The value `4270` is one example that is not recognized. Here is how I've confirmed its presence (pseudo-code):

```py
shotList = pd.read_csv(fileName,header=None,sep=' ')

    for i, shot in enumerate(shotList[0]):
                ! convert to int64 just for good measure...
                shot = np.int64(shot) 

                if shot == 4720: # pull value that isn't recognized
                        test == shot

                if shot in df['shotno']:
                        # perform some tasks...
```

[These are my tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YETlh.png)

[Here is what the larger Dataframe looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQfU8.png)

I know to be careful not to compare values of different types (e.g., `int`==`float`). Does this make any sense? Perhaps there is something weird happening earlier on in my script, but I've checked it twice and can't find the issue.

Comment: can you post the error trace?

Comment: There is no traceback. The issue is that the equivalence returns False instead of True.